# How to calculate integral with multiple embedded exponentials?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

$\int_K^\infty1-\exp(-\exp(-x))dx$

By change of variable we have $\int_0^{\exp(-K)}\frac{1-\exp(-u)}{u}du$ but I can't spit the two because integral of $\frac{1}{u}$ from 0 to K diverges, and therefore there will be an $\infty-\infty$ term when calculating the integral.

Wolframalpha gives but how?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
v\longmapsto\left[1-\exp\left(-Nve^{-\gamma/c}\right)\right]\exp(-\lambda v)
$$
has elementary primitive
$$
v\longmapsto
  \frac{e^{-Nv e^{-\gamma/c} + \gamma/c - \lambda v}}
       {\lambda e^{\gamma/c} + N}
- \frac{e^{-\lambda v}}
       {\lambda}.
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty\left[1-\exp\left(-Nve^{-\gamma/c}\right)\right]\exp(-\lambda v)\,dv = \frac{N}{\lambda(\lambda e^{\gamma/c} + N)},
$$
also with elementary primitive... (to be continued)

Comment: Why is it divergent? With a reasonable choice of parameters, the integrand is a difference of two decaying exponents.

Comment: @Maxim, we have a dangling $(\text{constant})v$

Comment: It just means your antiderivative is incorrect. Look at the integrand, its behavior at infinity is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use $G$ for the lower limit because reasons. Assume that all parameters are positive. The inner integral is elementary:
$$I(\gamma) =
\int_G^\infty (1 - \exp(-N v e^{-\gamma/c})) \,e^{-\lambda v} \,dv =
e^{-G \lambda} \left( \frac 1 \lambda - \frac
 {\exp \left(-G N e^{-\gamma/c} \right)}
 {N e^{-\gamma/c} + \lambda} \right).$$
The antiderivative of the result has a closed form in terms of the incomplete gamma function:
$$\int I(-c \ln u) \,d(-c \ln u) =
\frac {c e^{-G \lambda}} \lambda \left(
 \int \frac {e^{-G N u}} u du -
 \int \frac {N e^{-G N u}} {N u + \lambda} du -
 \ln u \right) =\\
\frac {c e^{-G \lambda}} \lambda
 (e^{G \lambda} \Gamma(0, G N u + G \lambda) - \Gamma(0, G N u) - \ln u).$$
$\Gamma(0, u)$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$ and is $-\ln u - \gamma_e + O(u)$ at $0^+$, $\gamma_e$ being Euler's constant. Therefore
$$\int_1^0 I(-c \ln u) \,d(-c \ln u) =
\frac c \lambda
 (\Gamma(0, G \lambda) - \Gamma(0, G N + G \lambda) +
  e^{-G \lambda} (\Gamma(0, G N) + \ln (G N) + \gamma_e)).$$

Comment: In that case both integrals are elementary if you change the order of integration.

Comment: @ZHU Everything is correct, you've answered your own question :).

Comment: @ZHU Just find the antiderivative of $1/(N w + \lambda)$. The singularity is at $w = -\lambda/N$, to the left of the interval of integration.

Comment: sorry that wasn't the right question either, I've updated the question I actually have.

Comment: @ZHU This answer already gives a solution for that: first the antiderivative of $e^{-u}/u$ and then the expansion of the antiderivative at $0^+$.

Comment: Do you mind to edit your answer a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific about which part is unclear. If you've looked at the second formula in the answer, can you write the antiderivative of $e^{-u}/u$?

Comment: but we can't seperate the 1/u term out isn't it? In your answer, can you change to integrate $\gamma$ instead of $v$

Comment: I'm talking about finding the antiderivative (the indefinite integral) as the first step. Then we can start worrying about the limits of integration.

Comment: I don't know it's not in my calculus textbook (sorry my math is very basic). Is it the exponential integral function? (from wolmframalpha)

Comment: Yes, it's the exponential integral, which alternatively can be written in terms of the incomplete gamma function (take the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition) and differentiate wrt $x$).

Comment: How about the other term? You can't subtract infinity by infinity isn't it?

Comment: Correct, you can't, which is why the last part of the answer talks about finding the limit of the antiderivative at $0^+$, not its value at $0$.

Comment: can you explain a bit more how you would do that?

Comment: First you actually write out the antiderivative, so you have something to work with. Then if you can get it into a form $\text{const} + O(u)$, you know what the limit is. To see how that expansion of $\Gamma(0, u)$ is derived, look at the Wikipedia link.

Comment: antiderivative is $\log(u)=\Gamma(0,u)-\gamma_e+O(u)$? Then what should I do?

Comment: Can you explain more or edit your answer?

Comment: Is there any good reference I can read about this?